# Error with spinner.setOnItemClickListener() inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, spinner

I'm new to Android development, I having some problem which unable to resolve.
I tried to implement a **Spinner** inside **Fragment**, now it having problems with the **spinner.setOnItemClickListener()** method,

It showing an error message:

> "setOnItemClickListener
>   (android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in Spinner cannot be
>   applied to (anonymous
>   android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener)

Here is my code:

```
public class CheckAvailabilityFragment extends Fragment {
  Spinner spinner;
  ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_check_availability, container,false);
    spinner = (Spinner)getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getBaseContext(),R.array.venue,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
    return rootView;
  }
}
```

Comment: The title and question do not match. Which error are you really asking about?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the title was edited, thanks for reminded! Is about spinner.setOnItemListener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you that `setOnItemClickListener()` takes a parameter of type `OnItemClickListener`. However, you are giving it a `OnItemSelectedListener`. Since `Spinner` doesn't support `OnItemClickListener`, you probably mean to call `onItemSelectedListener()` which takes a `OnItemSelectedListener` as its parameter.

Answer (score 2):

**setOnItemClickListener** will not works with spinner as been said at [Spinner SetOnItemClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)):

> A spinner does not support item click events. Calling this method will
>   raise an exception.
>
> Instead use
>   setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener).

Try using the following:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

  }
});
```

Comment: "setOnItemClickListener will not works with spinner. " that is not true. Spinner has this method or the OP would get an entirely different error message.

Comment: I've read it at [Spinner OnItemClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)), it say `A spinner does not support item click events. Calling this method will raise an exception.`. Or do I missing something here?

Comment: You are right. I missed that. I still think the bigger problem is the OP not understanding that the error message hints at the solution because the argument is the wrong type.

Comment: I definitely agree with you. OP could be confused by it without your clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

use `getActivity()` instead of `getBaseContext()`

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want `getBaseContext()`? You should be able to just pass `getActivity()` as the first parameter of `createFromResource()`

Comment: the reason I using getBaseContext() as this is a solution for me and I referred to a solution in other posts, but I couldn't find the post now.